# Pi 3 amixer error

Tags: audio, pi-3

I would like to use my headphones with the Pi 3.

So I changed the audio config in raspi-config.
This is the error I get:

[image]

Following the documentation, I used amixer. It gives this error:

[image]

The operating system and firmware are the latest versions.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the output of the following commands? `uname -a`, `lsmod`, `cat /etc/os-release`.

Comment: I am sorry.I do not have enough ruputation.I change the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `raspi-config` failed to make the needed change to `/boot/config.txt`.

You need to edit `/boot/config.txt` and add the following line.

`dtparam=audio=on`

You will need administrator privileges to edit the file so use

`sudo nano /boot/config.txt`

`nano` is a simple editor.  Use any editor you like.